# Compiling OpenCV on Pi 3

Tags: opencv

I have just successfully followed all steps provided at the following pg.
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/

When I want to compile the code with the following command ***pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.0.0/build $ make -j4,*** I get the following error msg:

***/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgcodecs/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp:248:1: fatal error: can’t write PCH file: No space left on device
 } // cv
 ^***
**compilation terminated.**

This is the awailable space I have on my Pi:n

- /dev/root          6128M 5767M       28M 100% /n
- devtmpfs            458M    0M      458M   0% /dev /n
- tmpfs               462M    0M      462M   0% /dev/shm /n
- tmpfs               462M   30M      433M   7% /run /n
- tmpfs                 5M    1M        5M   1% /run/lock /n
- tmpfs               462M    0M      462M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup /n
- /dev/mmcblk0p6       63M   22M       42M  34% /boot /n
- tmpfs                93M    1M       93M   1% /run/user/1000 /n
- /dev/mmcblk0p5       30M    1M       28M   2% /media/pi/SETTINGS /n

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

I recently built opencv3.2 (including contrib) and it ate around 1 GByte, excluding the sources. If you see 28 M free, this is likely what has been freed on cleanup after the build failed.

Add a USB stick and do the build there. You really need more space than you have available.

Comment: Thx for answering. I have now added the following: /dev/sda1       7.5G   18M  7.1G   1% /mnt/usbdrive. My next question would now be. Should I start the entire download process as described in the following URL: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/ and ensure that it is downloaded the the USB stick? Please guide me.  Thank you

Comment: Fine. Good luck. Let me know if you succeeded.

Comment: Sure I will keep you posted Philippos, but back to my question. Looking at my disk usage at my Pi, looks like I have used all awailable disk under root: /dev/root       6.0G  5.7G   21M 100% . Probably after all downloading done before I had mounted the USB. How can I remoove all unnecesay programs from the Pi, and then do a new re-install including the USB storage as a resource

Comment: Oh, sorry, somehow I missed the second part of your comment. Delete the build directory on your root drive, create a new one on the USB stick and build opencv there (the sources did fit in the root partition, so leave them there. Delete them after the build. Two remarks: 1) I formatted the new drive to ext4; I'm not sure whether you will run into problems if your stick is vfat. 2) Are you sure you want opencv 3.0? The current version is 3.2 and has some new optimizations for the arm platform.

Comment: And about your idea in the latest comment: I would not include a usb drive as regular part of your system. If your system is really too full even after deleting the opencv sources and build, better get a bigger µSD card.

Comment: Strange. I can not find any "build" directory when I do the following:   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -al /

Comment: I don't know how you did call it and where you did place it. I mean the directory from where you called the `cmake`. It should have a `CMakeCache.txt` in it, so `find ~ -name CMakeCache.txt` will show you the way

Comment: OK, I did the rm -rf build and it all got removed. Now I have /dev/root       6.0G  4.5G  1.3G  79% / which seems more like it I assume. Do you now sugest me to do the following: a) go to USB, b) create a the following directories: /opencv-3.0.0/build and run the cmake cmd from there of?

Comment: Exactly (if you really, really want the old opencv3.0.0)

Comment: And If I would like to remove the entire opencv3.0.0 and instead go with 3.2 version, I should probably run rm -rf on the entire opencv-3.0.0 directory. Right?

Comment: Yes. Then you can checkout the 3.2 to your usb drive as well

Comment: OK, following your advice Phillippos. ..O=)...What concerns me how do I ensure that I get all packages downloaded correctly that matches the 3.2 version. Any advice ?

Comment: Well, you clone the repo from opencv.org. If you need the contrib stuff as well, follow the instructions on where to clone and how to include it. It worked for me as they described it.

Comment: hmmmm, hard to find any manual to the Raspeberry Jessie OS . Do you know where to find it?

Comment: Raspbian 8? Mainly any Debian manual will do. One thing I forgot to mention: You should set the compiler flags for neon support and so on. It's a giant speedup!

Comment: Hi again Phillippo. Your help is fantastic....but as you probably have understood by now,  I am new to this and it starts to become a bit complicated. ...It would help me to have someone who knows doing this, working with me on my system ....:O=)...Espen